# How to find the first bit that is different in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to compare to Integers in C and the problem is to find the least significant bit that is different. What is the fastest way in C to do this ?

Example:

```
               Bit
               3210
               ----
a = 13 (binary 1101)
b = 9  (binary 1001)
                ^
```

The result here should be 2, because bit 2 is the first bit that is different.

Comment: Do a XOR and find the first set bit.

Comment: And for finding the first bit, either from the left or the right, look for a compiler intrinsic function; often this is provided natively by the hardware and exposed conveniently by the compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ffs()` from `<strings.h>` returns the position of the first bit set,
where the bits are numbered starting at `1` for the least significant bit
(and `ffs(0)` returns zero):

```
unsigned a = 0x0D;
unsigned b = 0x09;

unsigned x = a ^ b;
int pos = ffs(x) - 1;
if (pos == -1) {
   // a and b are equal
} else {
   // pos is the position of the first difference 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using a XOR now, but the __builtin_ffs in GCC instead of ffs from string.h !

Comment: Why cannot VS find `strings.h`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: strings.h (or string.h) is a POSIX extension to C, which might not be available on all standard-conforming C compilers.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: I did not test it, but for Visual Studio, [_BitScanForward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wfd9z0bb(v=vs.100).aspx) seems to do a similar job.

Answer (score 3):

[Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) offers an excellent collection of, er, bit twiddling hacks, with performance/optimisation discussion attached. For your problem (from that site), you can use multiply-and-lookup strategy:

```
unsigned int c = a ^ b;  
int r;           // result goes here
static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((c & -c) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

References:

- "[Using de Bruijn Sequences to Index a 1 in a Computer Word](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/debruijn.pdf)" - Explanation about why the above code works.

Comment: `c` is the **value** of the respective bit (like 1, 2, 4, 8, ...), not its **position** (like 0, 1, 2, 3, ...), right? http://ideone.com/CzzYFj

Comment: Don't use a signed integer for that. It is not guaranteed to use two's-complement arithmetic. **Use unsigned int**.

Comment: @self. Edited the answer to use multiply-and-lookup strategy.

Comment: @EOF Edited the answer to use multiply-and-lookup strategy.

Comment: @herohuyongtao The `Bit Twiddling Hacks` link alone is definitely worth an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdint.h>

int bit_count(uint32_t bits) {
    bits = (bits & 0x55555555) + (bits >> 1 & 0x55555555);
    bits = (bits & 0x33333333) + (bits >> 2 & 0x33333333);
    bits = (bits & 0x0f0f0f0f) + (bits >> 4 & 0x0f0f0f0f);
    bits = (bits & 0x00ff00ff) + (bits >> 8 & 0x00ff00ff);
    return (bits & 0x0000ffff) + (bits >>16 & 0x0000ffff);
}

int func(unsigned a, unsigned b){
    unsigned x = a ^ b;
    return x ? bit_count((x&(-x))-1) : -1;
}
```

Comment: @herohuyongtao It's just a subcontract function. It is better than using a logarithmic function to subcontract.